# Ms Access : Freeze Table Header in Report

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2007, ms-access-2010

i have a rather large report in MS Access , I would like to freez the table header,when scrolling down. Is this possible?

bR,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reports are for printing, the Print preview ist just that, a preview.

Since there is no "freezing a header" on paper, the answer is no.

But of course you can put the table header into the **page header** of the report, so it will show up on every page.

Answer (score 0):

You would probably have more success in presenting your report how you want if you use Excel to link to your database, much easier to produce visually appealing reports that way.